# How to change date format in python with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with big data in pandas and I have a problem with the format of the dates, this is the format of one column

```
Wed Feb 24 12:06:14 +0000 2021
```

and I think it is easier to change the format of all the columns with a format like this

```
'%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M:%S'
```

how can i do that?

Comment: `pandas.to_datetime('Wed Feb 24 12:06:14 +0000 2021').strftime('%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M:%S')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following function for your dataset.

```
def change_format(x):
format = dt.datetime.strptime(x, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z  %Y")
new_format = format.strftime('%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M:%S')
return new_format
```

Then apply it using `df['date_column'] = df['date_column'].apply(change_format)`.
Here `df` is your dataset.

Comment: I think this works but when I used it I have this problem... "time data 'nan' does not match format '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z  %Y'" and its weird because i don´t have any row with NaN and the data is in format 'str'

Answer (score 2):

Does this work for you?

```
pandas.to_datetime(s, format='%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M:%S')
```

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior